# .On not working after live update of html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dom

I have dynamically added below code to html

```
<input class="checkclass" lsid="d11" name="checkbox-mini-0" id="checkbox-mini-0" data-mini="true" type="checkbox">
```

Now i know .click wont work  , so other stackoverflow answers recomendded to use On ,.but still its not working

```
<script> 
$(document).on("click",".checkclass", function() {
alert("test"); 
});
</script>
```

My live url is at http://freegifts.in/diet/test.html

Comment: Looks like it should work to me. And it does: http://jsfiddle.net/jLqSH/1/

Comment: please check my live url..its not working :/ and no errors in console too

Comment: Sorry, i can't. Maybe someone else will.

Comment: Wrap this in a `$(document).ready(function() { //code });`

Comment: @Vishnu you do have error `-->`  Uncaught TypeError: Property 'scrollTo' of object [object global] is not a function

Comment: *"please check my live url..its not working"* No, that's not how it works. You present the problem **here**.

Comment: @tymeJV Why? that would require `document` to exist, which is the only thing this code requires anyway.

Comment: which browser @MohammadAdil ? i dont see any

Comment: http://freegifts.in/diet/css/jquery-ui.min.js 500 error. Should probably be http://freegifts.in/diet/ext/jquery-1.10.2.min.js

Comment: That url is not necessary !! please ignore that...i removed that line..still it dont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `checkbox`, `radio` and `select` elements, use `change` event not `click`. Those elements are wrapped in div once they are created so they don't receive any event directly.

Upon creating them, JQM bind events to parent div and accordingly fires event on those elements.

```
$(document).on("change", ".selector", function.
```

Comment: wooow :) you are always awesome bro :D genius